# Find max from Scalding UnsortedGrouped[String, Set[MyStuff]]

Tags: java, scala, scalding

I need to do the following:

- group my records by some String property
- discard groups that are too big
- retrieve the max element in each of the remaining groups

Here is what I got so far:

```
val records: TypedPipe[MyStuff] = ...
records
  .groupBy(_.getThatStringProperty)
  .toSet
  .filter(_._2.size < 10)
  ....
```

I end up with a `UnsortedGrouped[String, Set[MyStuff]]`. How do I find the 'max' MyStuff for each group in a way that it's elegant, parallelizable, and with minimum memory requirements?

Answer (score 0):

`.mapValues { _.max }` should do it